# How to quit two Selenium webdrivers?

Tags: python, macos, selenium, selenium-firefoxdriver

I'm trying to use two different browser windows and then eventually closing them. I can access each of them separately but when I try to close them both only `driver2` gets closed, no matter the focus.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver1 = webdriver.Firefox()
driver1.get("https://google.com/")

driver2 = webdriver.Firefox()
driver2.get("https://google.com/")

driver1.quit()
driver2.quit()
```

Is there another way to do this?

I'm using Geckodriver `v.0.21.0`, Firefox `v61.0.1` and Selenium `v3.13` on macOS High Sierra.

Comment: and `driver1 = webdriver.Firefox()
driver1.get("https://google.com/")
driver1.quit()

driver2 = webdriver.Firefox()
driver2.get("https://google.com/")
driver2.quit()` this one ?

Comment: @NarendraR That example works as expected.

Comment: What is your browser version ?

Comment: @NarendraR : It does not matter where you write quit() method. That particular browser instance has the particular driver focus.

Comment: @cruisepandey It was `v60.0.2`, I upgraded to `v61.0.1` but the same thing still happens.

Comment: Well, I am on windows 10 , selenium 3.12.0 , geckodriver 20.1 ,FF version 61.0 , and the code works fine. It is closing both the instance of ff browser.

Comment: FYI , this is how I have defined my driver : `driver1 = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path = r'C:/Users/abhishep/Downloads/geckodriver-v0.20.1-win64/geckodriver.exe')`

Comment: @cruisepandey I did the same and the issue still persists. Maybe it's a mac problem?

Comment: Yes to me , it's seems like OS specific issue.